# React include dynamic prop value in component name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to render a react component.  The first part of the component will remain the same, however the second part needs to change dynamically based on the data returned from the props.  Is there some way to concatenate these together?

```
import * as Icon from 'react-cryptocoins';

class ResultRow extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component-result-row">

        <Icon.{this.props.name}/>
      </div>
    );}}
```

Hardcoding the name works as expected

```
<{Icon.image1}/>
```

**Solution:**

```
import * as Icon from 'react-cryptocoins';

class ResultRow extends PureComponent {
  var name = this.props.name;
  var Component = Icon[symbol];
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="component-result-row">

       <Component/>
  </div>
);}}
```

Comment: Your line `<{Icon.{this.props.name}/>` has unmatched brackets.

Comment: try this  considering only it's an object {Icon[this.props.name]}

Comment: referring to it as an object doesn't work.  It doesn't return the proper output.

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f4e7pg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is store the value in a variable (should start with capital letter) then render that.

Like this:

```
class ResultRow extends PureComponent {
  render() {

    const Comp = Icon[this.props.name];

    return (
      <div className="component-result-row">
        <Comp />
      </div>
    );
}}
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve this by creating a variable and then accessing the proper element from the object using the variable.